# Poetry not found with docker

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to build the simplest of the docker image with poetry.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ARG APP_PATH=/app
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9
ARG POETRY_VERSION=1.1.13
ARG POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry"

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=$POETRY_VERSION \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1\
    POETRY_HOME=${POETRY_HOME}

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install curl -y \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python - --version ${POETRY_VERSION}



WORKDIR $APP_PATH
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock $APP_PATH

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

CMD ["poetry" "-V"]
```

The docker image builds fine.

But when i try to run it , it fails with

```
λ docker run test
/bin/sh: 1: [poetry: not found
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong here.

But this one works

```
docker run -it test /opt/poetry/bin/poetry -V
Poetry version 1.1.13
```

Modified Dockerfile to look like this

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "poetry" ]
CMD ["-V"]
```

and viola it works!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have access to `poetry` in my Docker build files, I always add the following lines to the beginning of the image build:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim

# use built-in pip to access poetry 
RUN pip install poetry

# start installing things with poetry
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml .
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install
```

Is this not the same for your use case? It seems like the most straight forward way to have access to poetry from within the container in my eyes?

Comment: Not sure what it is but this line ENTRYPOINT [ "poetry" ]
CMD ["-V"] is making a difference.Adding this line the command docker run test works

Comment: Great! Could you detail how I can edit my answer so that it can be accepted and we can close the thread?

Comment: There is a edit hyperlink with muted text to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recipe for installing Docker via pipx, which will work behind corporate VPNs. Security analysts will probably prefer this method.

Fill in the values for `${POETRY_VERSION}`, `${USER}`, `${UID}` and `${GID}`.

```
# Install pipx so we can install poetry system wide
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --user pipx && \
    python3 -m pipx ensurepath

# Now install poetry to install our dependencies
RUN pipx install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Copy our poetry configuration files to know what to install
COPY --chown=${UID}:${GID} pyproject.toml "/home/${USER}/work/"
COPY --chown=${UID}:${GID} poetry.lock    "/home/${USER}/work/"

# Install our package requirements via poetry. No venv. Squash max-workers error.
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry config installer.max-workers 10 && \
    poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root -vvv && \
    poetry cache clear pypi --all -n
```